# JavaVM->GetEnv: which JNI_VERSION to pass?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

It seems that at the moment the highest JNI version is JNI_VERSION_1_6, so that's probably what I should pass as the 2nd argument to `GetEnv`. But is there a more generic way to get the actual JNI version so that in future, when this version is incremented, I don't need to edit this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass the version that you need for the code you have written. No need to change it later unless you later use later APIs.